# Complete and minimal flexibility workout?

Tags: workout-routines, training, stretching, flexibility

I would like to increase my flexibility. Not necessarily every single part of my body but I would like to hit most if not all areas. I would like a set of several exercises that I can do one day or over several days for basically the rest of my life, to constantly improve my flexibility.

What is the simplest, most necessary/important/commonly used(as in the muscle's flexibility is needed commonly in real life situations, not the stretch itself is commonly used) set of stretches that I could do to increase full body flexibility?

Answer (score 4):

No static program will bring constant improvement. If you want to continue increasing flexibility over time, you need to do something like regularly attend a yoga class, where the exercises used progress over time and you're exposed to a wide variety of movements.

Comment: By static program do you mean a program consisting of static stretches? Or are you saying if I do the same set of stretches the results it yields will plateau. What if the stretches are done for longer and made more difficult (but essentially the same) like instead of touching your toes you touch your elbows to toes and then Progress to head to toes?

Comment: @Aequitas I mean the latter. What works now will stop working. What you need and are able to do now is different from what you will need and will be able to do later. It's not all just doing the same stretches further. Learning and variety are necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I could recommend some 'flows' like the 4 movement closed System from ido portal. https://youtu.be/D8QxbtcA5hU

I like those kind of stretch and mobility drills highly effective and timesaving also are more fun then static stretching routines.

Answer (score 3):

As in my answer [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24160/is-there-a-stretching-equivalent-of-the-food-pyramid/24161#24161), I'm a fan of Craig Ramsay's *[Anatomy of Stretching](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1607103982)*, which offers, along with a long list of stretches, both an hour-long comprehensive routine and a 15 minute "essentials" routine. Here is a low-res scan of the latter:

[image: Essential stretches]